# Request URI too long via POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sending a POST request via `Net` as such:

```
  http    = Net::HTTP.new(mixpanel_endpoint.host, mixpanel_endpoint.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(mixpanel_endpoint.request_uri)
  http.request(request)
```

The issue is that the request_uri is over the max limit. It's a BASE64 encoded string.

Does anybody know what to do about this?

```
<Net::HTTPRequestURITooLong 414 Request URI Too Long readbody=true>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error from `Net` or the endpoint you are trying to connect too?

Comment: added the error message

Comment: I think the error is because the endpoint is returning a 414 HTTP code.

Answer (score 1):

`Net::HTTPRequestURITooLong` is a 414 HTTP code from the server, you will need to change the request to conform to what the endpoint allows.

> 10.4.15 414 Request-URI Too Long
>
> The server is refusing to service the request because the Request-URI
>   is longer than the server is willing to interpret. This rare condition
>   is only likely to occur when a client has improperly converted a POST
>   request to a GET request with long query information, when the client
>   has descended into a URI "black hole" of redirection (e.g., a
>   redirected URI prefix that points to a suffix of itself), or when the
>   server is under attack by a client attempting to exploit security
>   holes present in some servers using fixed-length buffers for reading
>   or manipulating the Request-URI.

reference: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the data directly to the URL?

Try splitting out the endpoint URL from the data. For example:

```
Net::HTTP::Post.new(request_endpoint, "whatever_param_value=#{base64_encoded_data}")
```